# Sql Query Taking longer to execute than expected time

Tags: sql

I am trying to execute the query below but it's taking around 40mins.

```
select logentryid 
from (
     select * from logentry_payloaddata pd,
     logentry le
     where (
            pd.entryid=le.logentryid
       and
            le.eventdatetime=(trunc(sysdate) - 14)
     )
     order by le.logentryid asc
)
```

In table logentry there are 4,24,91,461 records and in logentry payload data there are 4,15,16,346 records (or "42,491,461" and "41,516,346" in some parts of the world, or even "42.491.461" and "41.516.346" in some other parts -- Ed.)

There are indexes on logentryid and entryid in resp tables.

Could someone please suggest what to do in this case.

Comment: Create index on eventdatetime?

Comment: It's the eventdatetime filter that's causing the issue.  I'm not sure what RDBMS this is, but you probably can't use an index since you are comparing to the output of a function.

Comment: also rewrite. looks like unnecessary nested selects. you could benefit from potentially only using the last 14 days from le as a subselect, then join that towards pd.

Comment: Please tell us your database system, the table structures and, if possible, the execution plan the database uses. Also, what do you mean by "4,24,91,461 records"? That number format looks strange...

Comment: @MaximilianMayerl - I **think** that he/she means that there are five records: "4, 24, 91, 461"

Comment: @Lamak: I don't think the query could possibly take 40 minutes if there were only that few records in each table.

Comment: @MaximilianMayerl - I know, I guess op was just giving an example of the records on each table

Comment: Actually, I think that it's the common Indian use of the *Lakh* (see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh).  I'll edit the question to good 'ole *'Merican*.

Comment: EDIT: @RBarryYoung: Ah, that's even more likely! Thank you for clarification!

Comment: @RBarryYoung - I had no idea about that, you are most likely correct

Answer (score 4):

Some suggestions:

1 - Index `eventdatetime` if it's not already

2 - Define a variable for `(trunc(sysdate) - 14)` - this will prevent the function from running for every row and will allow the use of the index from step 1

3 - Un-obfuscate your code.  Nesting is unneeded here and you are using an old-style `JOIN` syntax which can cause problems:

```
SELECT logentryid 
FROM logentry_payloaddata pd
INNER JOIN logentry le
   ON pd.entryid=le.logentryid
WHERE le.eventdatetime = @MyDateVariable
ORDER BY logentryid ASC
```

Comment: Why do you suggest the variable? What environments would recalculate this scalar constant on every row? *(Unless you mean that the implicit cast may be causing issues, in which cast doesn't just explicitly casting the scalar constant work?)*

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  le.logentryid
FROM
  logentry_payloaddata     pd
INNER JOIN
  logentry                 le
    ON pd.entryid=le.logentryid
WHERE
  le.eventdatetime = CAST(trunc(sysdate) - 14 AS DATETIME)
ORDER BY
  le.logentryid ASC
```

1).  Changed the layout *(using INNER JOIN, etc)* for my benefit, but doubt it will change performance.

2).  Added a `CAST()` to your date comparison.  Your code requires an *implicit* `CAST()` any way.  Using an *explicit* `CAST()` ensures that the constant is being cast, not the data field.  This matters greatly as it dictates how any indexes can, or can't, be used.

3).  Indexes - There is no single answer, it depends on the statistics of your data.

On the table `logentry_payloaddata` you definately need an index on `entryid`.

On the table `logentry` there are two different indexes that may help:
- `(logentryid, eventdatetime)`
- `(eventdatetime, logentryid)`

My best guess is that the latter will give the best performance.  But I'd recommend creating both and checking to see which is actually used.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select logentryid  
from logentry_payloaddata pd
inner join logentry le on pd.entryid=le.logentryid and le.eventdatetime=(trunc(sysdate) - 14)
```

You can put the where clause on to the inner join for quicker comparisons.

Also worth trying to use nolock if your database is being accessed/updated by multiple clients at the same time. Do read about using nolock first - you get results before other clients have performed a commit.

Comment: What are you basing "put the where clause on the inner join for quicker comparisons" on?  It will generate an identical execution plan in all versions of SQL Server, and just obfuscates where the filter is actually applied

Comment: I think this only true in sub queries. Wouldn't you agree that the boolean comparison 'pd.entryid=le.logentryid' is just as much as a filter as 'le.eventdatetime=(trunc(sysdate) - 14)' and should be in the same place (where clause or inner join).

Comment: No, the `pd.entryid=le.logentryid` is the JOIN CRITERIA and the `eventdatetime` filter is applied to the joined result set and should be in the where clause.

Comment: @user923721 - SQL is compiled to a plan and not executed 'as-is'. Both the `JOIN` and `,` versions will in-fact yield the same plan. Moving the conditions, between the `ON` clause and the `WHERE` clause, makes no difference at all in this case. You could even join `ON le.eventdatetime=(trunc(sysdate) - 14)` and filter with a `WHERE pd.entryid=le.logentryid` and *still* get the same plan. SQL compilers are not so simplistic that this will confound them.

Comment: JNK it's the same thing. "The join criteria for this join is that the id's match and the date = whatever'" The join criteria could equally be nothing (full outer join) and then you apply a filter of id's matching and the date=whatever